# How to fetch file name in Kendo Spreadsheet uploaded from file open button?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have created a Kendo spreadsheet on my project and I want to load the spreadsheet from the 'open file' button as below.

[image]

I want to get the uploaded/loaded file name to a JavaScript variable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [excelImport event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/spreadsheet#events-excelImport) passes the selected file in its event arguments. You can access the file name via e.file.name.

```js
function getFileName(e) {
  var fileName = e.file.name;
}
```